# Adding information based on an id columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem that I think it should be solvable with a loop but I am unsure on how to proceed. I am working with Pandas. I have two datasets: one with two columns of ids corresponding to my participants (`ID_dataframe`) and another with the actual `info_df`. I am including a simplified example of my situation below:

**ID_dataframe**

| ID-1 | ID-2 |
| --- | --- |
| A201 | SF-01 |
| B202 | SF-02 |
| C203 | SF-03 |
| D204 | SF-04 |

**Info_df**
.

| ID-1 | treatment | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A201 | A | 1 |
| A201 | B |  |
| A201 | C | 2 |
| B202 | A |  |
| B202 | C | 2 |
| C203 | A1 |  |
| C203 | A2 | 3 |
| D204 | B | 1 |

So I want to be able to incorporate ID2 from `ID_dataframe`  into the `info_dataframe` based on `ID-1` so it looks like this:

| ID-1 | ID2 | treatment | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A201 | SF-01 | A | 1 |
| A201 | SF-01 | B |  |
| A201 | SF-01 | C | 2 |
| B202 | SF-02 | A |  |
| B202 | SF-02 | C | 2 |
| C203 | SF-03 | A1 |  |
| C203 | SF-03 | A2 | 3 |
| D204 | SF-04 | B | 1 |

I imagine it should be fairly easy but I can't figure it out :(
I would appreciate any help!

Comment: `Info_df.merge(ID_dataframe, how='left', on='ID-1').fillna('').iloc[:, [0, 3, 1, 2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map`, `merge` and `join` will work also, albeit a little slower:

```
Intro_id['ID2'] = Intro_id['ID-1'].map(ID_dataframe.set_index('ID-1')['ID-2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `join` operation.
You can refer to [Dataframe Joins](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for reference.

In this case, you could join the `Info_df` with `ID_dataframe` on `ID-1` columns in both the dataframes. This can be done by:

```
Info_df.join(ID_dataframe.set_index('ID-1'), on='ID-1')
```

This should return the table you want.